# How to connect to peap(wpa2) in linux?

Tags: shell

I cannot connect to peap in gentoo linux.

```
wpa_supplicant&wpa_cli&so on

$ wpa_supplicant -D nl80211 -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -B
iw wlp2s0 link
```

> not connected

Answer (score 0):

the peap connection in my phone[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m4QZ.png)

and it can be connected in my phone with others stay (don't need to verify CA certificate)